# Showing specific button to current user in Android

Tags: android, firebase, button

My app has a post layout which have an edit button and the send button. All i want to do is to show only edit button if current user is viewing his/her post and not the send button. Just like a stackoverflow post, you can't edit other's post and can't send a message to yourself. I have tried boolean methods but still no solution. Thanks.

Activity that have showButtonsForCurrentUser() method ;

```
public class ViewPostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "ViewPostActivity";
    //widgets
    private TextView mTitle, mDescription, mPrice, mLocation;

    //vars
    private String mPostId;
    private String userId;
    private Post mPost;
    private PostImages mPostImages;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ImageView editPostIcon;
    private WormDotsIndicator wormDotsIndicator;
    public ViewAdapter viewAdapter;
    public DatabaseReference reference;
    public FirebaseUser currentUser;
    public ArrayList<String> IMAGES = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Uri> mImageUris = new ArrayList<>();
    private SquareImageView postImageView;
    private User user;

    //Dialog and Sheet vars
    private Dialog deleteDialog;
    private Button deleteBtnDialog;
    private Button deleteBtnSheet;
    private Button updateBtn;
    private Button sendBtn;
    private TextView titleTv, messageTv;
    private ImageView closeIcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_post);

        mPostId = getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.arg_post_id));

        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        mDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_description);
        mPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_price);
        mLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_location);
        postImageView = findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.send_msg);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager_images);
        editPostIcon = findViewById(R.id.edit_post_btn);
        wormDotsIndicator = findViewById(R.id.dotsindicator);

        editPostIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showBottomSheetDialog();
            }
        });

        getPostInfo();
        showButtonsForCurrentUser();

        ////MyPosts Layout/////
        deleteBtnDialog = findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn);
        deleteDialog = new Dialog(this);
        ////MyPosts Layout/////

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewPostActivity.this, MessageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userId", userId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void showButtonsForCurrentUser(){
        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        //sendBtn and editPostIcon are set to GONE.
        if (currentUser.equals(userId)){
            sendBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            editPostIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    private void getPostInfo(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getPostInfo: getting the post information.");

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        Query query = reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                .orderByKey()
                .equalTo(mPostId);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot singleSnapshot = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
                if(singleSnapshot != null){
                    mPost = singleSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found the post: " + mPost.getTitle());

                    mTitle.setText(mPost.getTitle());
                    mDescription.setText(mPost.getDescription());

                    String price = "FREE";
                    if(mPost.getPrice() != null){
                        price = "$" + mPost.getPrice();
                    }
                    mPrice.setText(price);
                    String location = mPost.getCity();

                    mLocation.setText(location);
                    userId = mPost.getUser_id();

                    if (mPost.getImage() != null){
                        wormDotsIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        postImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Picasso.get().load(mPost.getImage()).into(postImageView);
                    }else {
                        IMAGES = mPost.getPostImages();
                        for (int i = 0; i <IMAGES.size(); i++){
                            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(IMAGES.get(i));
                            mImageUris.add(myUri);
                        }

                        viewAdapter = new ViewAdapter(getApplication(), IMAGES);
                        viewPager.setAdapter(viewAdapter);
                        wormDotsIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void showBottomSheetDialog() {
        final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(ViewPostActivity.this, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_update_container);
        View bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_update, linearLayout);
        updateBtn = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.update_btnn);
        deleteBtnSheet = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btnn);

        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
        bottomSheetDialog.show();

        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent updateActivityIntent = new Intent(ViewPostActivity.this, UpdateActivity.class);
                if (IMAGES != null){
                    updateActivityIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("IMAGES", IMAGES);
                    updateActivityIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("IMAGEURIS", mImageUris);
                }else {
                    String singlePhotoUrl = mPost.getImage();
                    updateActivityIntent.putExtra("Single Photo url", singlePhotoUrl);
                }

                updateActivityIntent.putExtra("Başlık", mTitle.getText());
                updateActivityIntent.putExtra("Açıklama", mDescription.getText());
                updateActivityIntent.putExtra("Fiyat", mPrice.getText());
                updateActivityIntent.putExtra("mPostId", mPostId);

                startActivity(updateActivityIntent);
                bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        deleteBtnSheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDeleteDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showDeleteDialog(){
        deleteDialog.setContentView(R.layout.positive_dialog);
        closeIcon = deleteDialog.findViewById(R.id.close_dialog);
        deleteBtnDialog = deleteDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn);
        titleTv = deleteDialog.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
        messageTv = deleteDialog.findViewById(R.id.message_dialog);

        closeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        deleteDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        deleteDialog.show();

        deleteBtnDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deletePost(mPostId);

                finish();
                overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
                startActivity(getIntent());
                overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);

                deleteDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    private void deletePost(String deletePostId){

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(getString(R.string.arg_post_id), deletePostId);

        Query deleteQuery = reference.child("posts").orderByChild("post_id").equalTo(deletePostId);
        deleteQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot delData: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    delData.getRef().removeValue();

                    Intent backIntent = new Intent(ViewPostActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(backIntent);
                }
                Toast.makeText(ViewPostActivity.this,"Data Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewPostActivity.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void status(String status){
        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(currentUser.getUid());

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("status", status);
        reference.updateChildren(hashMap);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        status("online");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        status("offline");
    }

    
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

what are the values for mPostId?
I would log the userID and currentuser values thats being retrieved, to check if there is no issue your query. The boolean part should work